# How can I append HTML to the end of a <div> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<div>`:

```
<div class="choose_radio rounded_border" style="border: 1px solid rgb(239, 126, 88);">
    <input type="radio" class="radio required error" name="ContactNewExisting" value="new" id="ContactNew" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">New Business</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="ContactNewExisting" value="existing" id="ContactExisting" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">Existing Business?</label>
</div>
```

and I want to append this `<label>`:

```
<label class="error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>
```

so the final outcome is like this:

```
<div class="choose_radio rounded_border" style="border: 1px solid rgb(239, 126, 88);">
    <input type="radio" class="radio required error" name="ContactNewExisting" value="new" id="ContactNew" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">New Business</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="ContactNewExisting" value="existing" id="ContactExisting" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">Existing Business?</label>
<label class="error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that with jQuery?

Comment: is this div have a specific id? or you want to append every div which has the same class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.choose_radio').append('<label class="error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/append/

I wouldn’t recommend using a `<label>` tag though. `<label>`s are intended to be labels for a single form field, and specify that form field via the `for` attribute. Your error message doesn’t apply to a single field, so it can just be a plain `<p>`, maybe with `<em>` or `<strong>` inside it for emphasis as it’s an error message.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `append` method to add the element as an HTML snippet:

```
$('.choose_radio').append(
  $('<label class="error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>')
);
```

Or as an element:

```
$('.choose_radio').append(
  $('<label/>', { 'class': 'error', generated: 'true' })
  .text('This field is required.')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:-

```
<!-- Assign an id to the div -->
<div id="myDiv" class="choose_radio rounded_border" style="border: 1px solid rgb(239, 126, 88);">
    <input type="radio" class="radio required error" name="ContactNewExisting" value="new" id="ContactNew" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">New Business</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="ContactNewExisting" value="existing" id="ContactExisting" style="color: rgb(179, 180, 180); cursor: default;">
    <label for="ContactNewExisting" class="radio_new" style="color: rgb(255, 51, 51); cursor: default; margin: 0pt 2px; font-size: 110%;">Existing Business?</label>
</div>
```

In the Javascript:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myDiv").append("<label class=\"error\" generated=\"true\">This field is required.</label>");  
});
```

Here's my test: http://jsfiddle.net/deAye/